# If $T$ is a transformation on a nonempty set $X$, then a point that is periodic for the transformation $T^3$ is also periodic for $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that if $T$ is a transformation on a nonempty set $X,$ then a point that is periodic for the transformation $T^3$ is also then periodic for $T$?

Comment: What do you mean by periodic? And have you tried solving this question?

Comment: What if $T$ is rotation one-third of the way around?

Comment: Are you still there, 486934? Anything to say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has abandoned it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If $x$ is periodic for a transformation $K$ that implies that there must be some natural number $n$ for which $(K^n)x=x$.

So, if $x$ is periodic for the transformation $T^3$, then...

And then looking instead at the transformation $T$, then using the same values of... we have...